# Disable HTML rendering with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Hi I am new to MVC and I am trying to make a table that shows alternate colour rows.  Something like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {

var result = "";
var styleWhite = @"style=""background-color:white""";
var styleBlue = @"style=""background-color:blue""";

if ( (item.ID % 1) == 0 )
{ result = styleBlue; }
else
{ result = styleWhite; }

<tr @result  >
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CALLTYPE)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DESCRIPTION)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

However the double quote keeps rendering as "&quote" like this:

```
<tr style=&quot;background-color:blue&quot;  >
```

Is there a way to suppress the rendering and get the double quote (or single quote) inside the tag?
Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Razor engine by default always HtmlEncodes any string. If you need to override this use

```
@Html.Raw(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
<tr @Html.Raw(result)  >
```

Also should be mod 2 and not 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use a single quote instead:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {

var result = string.Empty;
var styleWhite = @"style='background-color:white'";
var styleBlue = @"style='background-color:blue'";

if ( (item.ID % 1) == 0 )
{ result = styleBlue; }
else
{ result = styleWhite; }

<tr @result  >
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CALLTYPE)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DESCRIPTION)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it renders to "&39".  Seems that @Html.Raw as per below seems to work.